# Wordpress files are deleting sutomatically

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on WordPress live site and realised that WordPress files (Most of the time **index.php** and **config.php**) are deleting automatically.

I have scanned all the files with Anti-Malware plugin and removed the script but still, we are facing the same issues. Can you please anyone help us?

Comment: probably the malware is still there and it is trying to overwrite your files with a hijack code (that usually starts with eval,iframe,gzinflate or base64) but fails due to insufficient permissions. the malware could potentially be installed in your database or as a plugin/theme file or code. Have a look at this to search your db for any malware: https://www.fixrunner.com/how-to-scan-wordpress-for-malware/ and my recommendation is to rename plugins/themes folders and create fresh ones and do not upload your theme before you search every file for these keywords (eval,iframe,gzinflate,base64)

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply.. we have tried this and more settings but still we are facing issues.

Comment: In that case, The backdoor is residing somewhere in another website on your server. If you are on dedicated/VPS Please scan your entire server with clamav.